# How can I improve the speed of large matrix multiplication in Julia

Tags: julia

There are two matrix A and B. The dimension of A and B are both 100000 by 100000.  Matrix B is a symmetric matrix. I would like to calculate A*B*A. I just use the julia code

```
A*B*A
```

to do that. But it will take a long time. I am just wondering if there is any better ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If they’re 32-bit dense matrices, those are 40 gigabytes each. Unless they have some kind of special structure like sparsity or that they’re a low rank product, it will be hard to do much better than just multiplying them directly. If they are sparse or low rank somehow, then you can probably take advantage of that somehow but we don't have enough information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I saved the matrix in csv format. Each matrix is 192 GB. I have to first import them to julia. I am running the matrix multiplication in high performance computer. I can request 2000 GB memory. I calculated it successfully but it takes me a long time. Thus, I am seeking for help.

Comment: Sorry, I did the arithmetic wrong—they'd be 40GB each not 40TB. Big but not impossible to work with. How are you getting them being 192GB each? Are they sparse matrices?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not sparse matrix. I saved them as csv file. The csv file is 192 GB for each matrix. I am a beginner for julia. I am just wondering if I can reduce the running time or memory usage. The primary issue is the running time.

Comment: You can try MKL but it’s unlikely to be much faster. If there’s no more structure to the problem then there’s not much to be improved. You’re computing matrix products and BLAS libraries are the most heavily optimized code in the world to do exactly that.

Comment: Regarding the 192GB figure, it seems like they may be stored in I,J,V format in the CSV, which is very inefficient for dense data, and then compressed.

Comment: This is very old (v0.7) and the syntax is no longer relevant but the idea still holds to speed up parallel processing of symmetric matrices.  https://github.com/TomConlin/ParTriAlloc